# Редактирование файла средствами языка Turbo Pascal (ситуация с перегруженными строками)

Tags: pascal, алгоритм

Всем доброго времени суток! Ситуация такая: есть текстовый файл (файл субтитров), в котором начиная с определённой строки каждая последующая строка строится примерно таким образом:

```
<Время появления субтитра в кадре>:<Время исчезновения>:<настройки шрифта>,,сам субтитр
```

И есть проблема – субтитры сбиты, скажем, на пару секунд начиная с определённого момента. Смотреть в таком случае малость неудобно, и мы пишем программу. На Паскале. Программа открывает один файл для чтения, другой - для перезаписи и копирует все строки подряд, изменяя то, что нам надо. Казалось бы, всё просто замечательно, но возникает ещё одна проблема – Паскаль при всей своей добросовестности не может запихать в переменную строки больше 255 символов, что обрекает на «ручное» редактирование файла после того как он сформируется.

И собственно возникает вопрос, можно ли средствами языка Паскаль решить поставленную задачу и обойти при этом возникшую проблему? Может даже можно обойтись без копирования строк, создания нового файла? Повторюсь, меня интересуют только возможность реализации в Паскале.

Comment: Работать с файлом, как с бинарным, не пробовали? Или читать файл в массив байт/чаров?

Comment: Была мысль работать блок-ридами, блок-врайтами. По идее должно помочь, если они поедают идентификатор конца строки, но, если честно, ещё не экспериментировал

Comment: имхо, $X+ и PChar...

Comment: Расширенный синтаксис? Да, этого я недоглядел, а если {$X} возможен и в Turbo, то возможно он станет решением проблемы. Посмотрим, что из всего этого выйдет

Comment: @Dex, как с бинарным это грубовато, в Паскале есть замечательная декларация `file of Char`. Но в обоих случаях ответственноть за обнаружение конца строки ляжет на программиста.

Comment: @karmadro4, грубовато или не грубовато, но `file of Char` - это объявление бинарного файла.

Comment: О господи, кто-то еще пишет под Турбо Паскаль до сих пор?

Comment: @Barmaley, это типиченая задачка с ограничениями, см. предыдущий вопрос от ОПа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хех, пока я возился с борландейскими дрѣвностями, почти всю теорию уже сказали.

Итак, результатъ исследования на условиях [GPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html):

```
program longline;

var
  Buffer: packed array [0..64849] of Сhar; { набить сегмент данных под завязку }

begin
  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), #0); { на всякий случай хвост буфера обнулю }
  while not Eof(Input) do
  begin
    Readln(Buffer);
    Writeln(Buffer);
  end;
end.
```

---

```
>tpc longline.pas
Turbo Pascal  Version 7.0  Copyright (c) 1983,92 Borland International
LONGLINE.PAS(14)
14 lines, 2144 bytes code, 65520 bytes data.
```

Сегмент данных выравнивается по границе параграфа, поэтому при добавлении еще одного чара линкер плюётся `Error 49: Data segment too large.`

---

Тестовый прогон на текстовом файле со одинаковыми строками длиной 40k символов:

```
>longline.exe < longline.in > longline.out
```

---

```
>fc /b longline.in longline.out
Сравнение файлов longline.in и LONGLINE.OUT
FC: различия не найдены
```

Как показывает FC, выходной файл полностью идентичен входному.

---

Таким образом, TP7 может вводить и выводить строки длиной ок. 63k символов, хотя нативный тип и ограничен длиной 255 символов. Дополнительные ~600 символов можно получить разместив буфер не в сегменте данных, а в куче.

Comment: С хайлайтером надо что-то делать...

Comment: Да надо наверно сделать указание языка подсветки...